# In a stored proc, how to insert records unique on month and year by checking destination table?

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, stored-procedures

I'm doing an `INSERT-SELECT`.  Got two tables like this:

```
DATE        Value
1/23/2013   x
2/12/2013   y
3/15/2013   z
```

DESTINATION:

```
DATE        Value
1/13/2013   xx
3/20/2013   xx
3/12/2014   xx
```

March 2013 exists, so I only want to insert the Jan and Feb records.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending how you're getting the data something along the lines of what is below will work. the `WHERE` clause is what is important

```
INSERT INTO destination (date, value)
SELECT date, value
FROM currenttable
WHERE CAST(month(dpartdate) AS VARCHAR)+'/'+CAST(year(dpartdate) AS VARCHAR) NOT IN (
  SELECT CAST(month(dpartdate) AS VARCHAR)+'/'+CAST(year(dpartdate) AS VARCHAR)
  FROM destination)
```

Comment: I think that you meant for your subquery to use the `destination` table, instead of `currenttable`?

Comment: How do you match up month and year?

Comment: @KKKKKKKK are you using a `datetime` or `timestamp` data type for the column? I've updated my answer to hopefully address your issue.

Comment: Datetime.  This isn't working: `SELECT Month(date)+' '+Year(date) FROM destination`.  It only returns the year.

Comment: Looks like you need to `CAST` the dates, so they don't add the two values together. I've updated my answer.